# MATLAB loop optimization

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, vectorization

I have a matrix, **matrix_logical(50000,100000)**, that is a sparse logical matrix (a lot of falses, some true). I have to produce a matrix, **intersect(50000,50000)**, that, for each pair, *i,j*, of rows of **matrix_logical(50000,100000)**, stores the number of columns for which rows *i* and *j* have both "true" as the value.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
% store in advance the nonzeros cols
for i=1:50000
    nonzeros{i} = num2cell(find(matrix_logical(i,:)));
end

intersect = zeros(50000,50000);

for i=1:49999
    a = cell2mat(nonzeros{i});
    for j=(i+1):50000
        b = cell2mat(nonzeros{j});
        intersect(i,j) = numel(intersect(a,b));
    end
end
```

Is it possible to further increase the performance? It takes too long to compute the matrix. I would like to avoid the double loop in the second part of the code.

**matrix_logical** is sparse, but it is not saved as sparse in MATLAB because otherwise the performance become the worst possible.

Comment: Note that `intersect` is probably a bad choice of variable name, as there's already an [`interesect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/intersect.html) function.

Comment: Have you thought about using `pdist()` with custom distance function giving the result you want?

Comment: @Eugenio: the result matrix you want to produce (assuming it has `single` class type) is too big to fit in memory `50000*50000*4/2^30 = 9.31 GB`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the [i,j] entry counts the number of non zero elements in the element-wise multiplication of rows i and j, you can do it by multiplying `matrix_logical` with its transpose (you should convert to numeric data type first, e.g `matrix_logical = single(matrix_logical)`):

```
inter = matrix_logical * matrix_logical';
```

And it works both for sparse or full representation.

**EDIT**

In order to calculate `numel(intersect(a,b))/numel(union(a,b));` (as asked in your comment), you can use the fact that for two sets `a` and `b`, you have

```
length(union(a,b)) = length(a) + length(b) - length(intersect(a,b))
```

so, you can do the following:

```
unLen = sum(matrix_logical,2);
tmp = repmat(unLen, 1, length(unLen)) + repmat(unLen', length(unLen), 1);
inter = matrix_logical * matrix_logical';
inter = inter ./ (tmp-inter);
```

Comment: Good answer! You need to convert `matrix_logical` to a numeric matrix however (`single(matrix_logical)`).

Comment: @Itamar Thanks for the answer; my code actually needs the intersection over the union (I deleted the second part just to keep the code simpler) so:
`intersection(i,j) = numel(intersect(a,b))/numel(union(a,b));`
is it still possible to apply your method?

Comment: In that case, you might consider accepting it (as well as accepting answers to other questions you post, as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want a logical AND of the rows:

```
intersct = zeros(50000, 50000)
for ii = 1:49999
    for jj = ii:50000
        intersct(ii, jj) = sum(matrix_logical(ii, :) & matrix_logical(jj, :));
        intersct(jj, ii) = intersct(ii, jj);
    end
end
```

Doesn't avoid the double loop, but at least works without the first loop and the slow find command.

Comment: The question is: if `matrix_logical` is *very* sparse, could this be slower than the OP's original code?

Comment: The first loop actually is not a problem, it is fast enough; the problem is with the second part of the code.

Comment: @Oli Hmm, you're right, it would probably be possible to construct an example where my code is slower that the OP code. Anyway, Itamar presented a much more elegant solution that even works with real sparse matrices in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment, here is a distance function suitable for `pdist()`

```
function out = distfun(xi,xj)
    out = zeros(size(xj,1),1);
    for i=1:size(xj,1)
        out(i) = sum(sum( xi & xj(i,:) )) / sum(sum( xi | xj(i,:) ));
    end
```

In my experience, `sum(sum())` is faster for logicals than `nnz()`, thus its appearance above.

You would also need to use `squareform()` to reshape the output of `pdist()` appropriately:

```
squareform(pdist(martrix_logical,@distfun));
```

Note that `pdist()` includes a `'jaccard'` distance measure, but it is actually the Jaccard *distance* and not the Jaccard *index* or *coefficient*, which is the value you are apparently after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't try it because I finally used the solution proposed by Itamar.